# How to select sub brackets from code using regex and substitute values

Tags: regex, string, python-3.7

Just a basic question related to python regex.
My code is this

```
void main void() 
{
abc
 {
 tune
 }
 {
 wao
 }
}
```

i want to replace the abc ,tune and wao with different values like abc=u, tune=p and wao=m.

I am unable to select these two sub brackets of code in my regex.

The Regex which i am using is `\{([^}]+)\}`.
I want to write a code which can substitute these values in such a way that first all sub brackets were substituted i.e (tune=p and wao=m) then main brackets are substituted (abc=u).

Comment: Very difficult using regex, better to do stateful parsing

Answer (score 1):

If you *do* want to make use of regex, the following will work for the given example:

```
import re

code = """void main void()
{
abc
 {
 tune
 }
 {
 wao
 }
}
"""

code = re.sub(r"({\s*)[^{\s]+(\s*{)", r"\1u\2", code)
code = re.sub(r"({\s*)[^{\s]+(\s*})(?=\s*{)", r"\1p\2", code)
code = re.sub(r"({\s*)[^{\s]+(\s*})(?=\s*})", r"\1m\2", code)
print(code)
```

Output:

```
void main void()
{
u
 {
 p
 }
 {
 m
 }
}
```

But in general cases it is recommended to do a stateful parsing as @wim suggests.

Comment: can u do this code with stateful parsing?

Comment: I’m afraid I cannot. Regex is not a parser. If your requirement of replacement is not so complicated, we can do it with small tweaks of the regex above. If it has a lot of varieties in terms of the structure of the brackets (nesting level etc.), we will need to start with a different approach.

Comment: I need to extract all the code within brackets and then use that extracted code to further processing so i may be need more than 1000+ lines of code in which function within a function is used so brackets are used within a brackets. so i need a code that can detect brackets within a brackets and can extract the codes from it for further processing.

Comment: Can you provide some actual examples which are minimal but enough to cover the possible variations to clarify the requirements?

Comment: 'strings_s strings[] =
{  #define s_file 0
 {"\xCB\x95\x99\x95", 0},
#define s_filess 1
{"\xC4\xDE\xC8\x9E\x9F\x83\xC8\xD5\xC8", 0},
#define s_mute 2
{"\xCC\xDE\xC9\x80\x9B\x86\x9D\x94\x99\x94\x94\x9A\xF2", 0},
}'

in this code the string function have their own brackets and the defined strings has his own brackets. so i am using this regex r"\{([^]+)([^{]+)\}" to only get the strings function brackets but instead of detecting strings function both brackets { & }. this regex only finds the first bracket { of 'String' function and bracket of define s_file function }

Comment: Thank you for the info. Would you please update your question with the code, not writing it in the comment? Otherwise it is not easy to retrieve the code due to loss of indents and line-breaks. In addition it will be helpful if you can specify the expected output literally. BR.